# Get users profile picture in circle image view

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have implemented Facebook login into my app and now want to get the users profile picture, i have done this but am now trying to turn it into a circle format using this library - https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

I am having trouble implementing the two together and am not sure the best way to go around it

Here is the java

```
final RoundedImageView profilePic = (RoundedImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myProfilePic);
    GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
            if (user != null) {
                // set the profile picture using their Facebook ID
                profilePic.setProfileId(user.optString("id"));
            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

And here is the xml

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/myProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip"

        android:scaleType="center"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_border_width="3dip"
        app:riv_oval="false"
        app:riv_border_color="@color/material_white"
        />
```

I am getting error

> Cannot resolve method 'SetProfileId'

I think the error is because I am not returning a proper bitmap in the graph request, but not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`RoundedImageView`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/master/roundedimageview/src/main/java/com/makeramen/roundedimageview/RoundedImageView.java) source I don't see any method called `setprofileId()`. You will need to make a request to Facebook Graph API to get the URL to the profile picture, and then either hand it to the view (if it has such method), or download it yourself and pass it as a `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am interested in downloading it myself as i think it will be easier to work with but i cant find any information on how to do that. What do you suggest would be the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Look at how you can get the URL using Graph API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/

Comment: Thankyou for the help i actually managed to complete this by getting the uri over Graph Request and then submitting it to Facebooks fresco which has a built in method for transforming the image into a circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using picasso

Below is the code :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL)
            .error(drawable)
            .placeholder(drawable)
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation()).into(imgView);

public class RoundedTransformation implements Transformation {
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    try {

        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public String key() {
    return "circle";
}
```

}